# How to get separate daily array from the weather API array (For React Redux) which gives a 5 days every 3 hours report

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

The Openweather API provides 5 days forecast for every 3 hours. We need to display data only for the current day. How can I separate the data for the current day and bind data only for the current day and each hour in that day? Here is the code:

Data looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0062,
"cnt": 39,
"list": [
  {
    "dt": 1540177200,
    "main": {
      "temp": 24.55,
      "temp_min": 20.88,
      "temp_max": 24.55,
      "pressure": 1008.67,
      "sea_level": 1025.96,
      "grnd_level": 1008.67,
      "humidity": 58,
      "temp_kf": 3.67
    },
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "02d"
      }
    ],
    "clouds": {
      "all": 8
    },
    "wind": {
      "speed": 3.82,
      "deg": 340.5
    },
    "sys": {
      "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-10-22 03:00:00"
  },
  {
    "dt": 1540188000,
    "main": {
      ...
    },
  },
  {
    "dt": 1540198800,
    "main": {
     ...
    },
  },
  {
    "dt": 1540587600,
    "main": {
      . . .
    }
  }
]
}
```

Redux Saga

```
export const fetchWeatherListStart = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FETCH_WEATHER_START
});
...
    import { takeLatest, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
    function* fetchWeatherSaga(){
     try {
    const weatherResponse = yield fetch("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02")
    const weatherlist = yield weatherResponse.json()
    yield put(fetchWeatherSuccess(weatherlist));
    } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchWeatherError(error.message));
      }
    }
    export default function* watchFetchWeatherSaga(){
        yield takeLatest("FETCH_WEATHER_START", fetchWeatherSaga)
    }
```

**Reducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  weatherList: null,
  isFetching: false,
  errorMessage: undefined
};
const fetchWeatherListReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_WEATHER_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case "FETCH_WEATHER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        weatherlist: action.payload
      };
    case "FETCH_WEATHER_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default fetchWeatherReducer;
```

**Component**

```
 export const WeatherPage = ({ fetchWeatherListStart}) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchWeatherListStart();
      }, [fetchWeatherListStart]);
...
```

I thought about using a selector but not sure if it's the best approach... How can be it solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on reducer level, the only thing you need is the current date stamp

```
case "FETCH_WEATHER_SUCCESS":
     // pass today's date along when calling this action
     const myDate = action.payload.todayDate
     // get only data for today
     const filteredList = action.payload.list.filter(item => item.dt === myDate) 

     return {
          ...state,
          isFetching: false,
          weatherlist: filteredList
     };
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it